# laravel 5 how to read barcode from sacnner to my application

Tags: php, laravel-5

I generate abarcode in laravel 5.2 by the package milon/barcode easily.My question  how to read this bar-code from scanner that connected with computer to use this bar-code in my application .Please  any one help me

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. From buying your own scanner with a built-in app for reading barcodes. Or create your own reader using JAVA, .NEt or others. To using web plugins or creating a mobile app. Plenty of ways to do this. Which have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanner always read the bar-code and output it as a string..

You should force a focus on where you want it to appear(eg. input form), then it will be filled with the string from the scanner when user scan something.